# Frequency Counter Problem

Tags: frequency-measurement

I'm a Electrical Engineering Student and i have to respond to this question before I can do the lab work. 
"A frequency counter with an internal 1MHz oscillator and six frequency dividers is given to measure the frequency of a 1250Hz signal. Determine the counter indication if the time base is in position 10s. For a 50Hz signal would it be more appropriate to measure frequency or period? What about the initial signal? Justify."

The problem is when we did a similar exercise in class we called different names to the frequencies, Im guessing that the base frequency is the 1MHz, and the input frequency is the 1250Hz and the 50Hz, so we should mesure the 1250 hz wave with frequency (fsignal > fcritical)and the 50hz with period (fsignal < fcritical) ?, and i don't understand what the 10 seconds are for ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem expects you to understand and compare two different ways of measuring frequency:

Count cycles in a known time.

Measure the period of a known number of cycles.

Method 1 should be obvious.

Note that method 2 requires some way to time a period.  One way is to run a known frequency into a counter for the length of the unknown period.

This should be enough to *think* about the problem, which is the point of the exercise.  Nobody here is going to just give you the answer to a homework problem.